# type casting in gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

How to cast String value to Integer type in gremlin console with AWS Neptune GDB.
I'm having the property 'age' with the string value, which needs to be converted to Integer type for math operations in the query.
all suggestions are appreciated.

I tried below queries suggested by kelvin.But got these exceptions.

```
    gremlin> g.V(1).values('age').map{(String)it}.next()
    Script336735.groovy: 1: [Static type checking] - Inconvertible types:cannot cast org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traverser <E2 extends java.lang.Object> to java.lang.String
    gremlin> g.V(1).values('age').map{(Integer)it}.next()
    Script336963.groovy: 1: [Static type checking] - Inconvertible types: cannot cast org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traverser <E2 extends java.lang.Object> to java.lang.Integer
```

**My requirement is to cast String value to Integer/long**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Kelvin.
Finally, This query works with AWS-Neptune GraphDB.

```
gremlin> g.V(1).values('age').map{(''+it).toInteger()}
==>25
```

instead of toInteger(), we can use some other java methods similar to that.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you managed to get it working. Hopefully I at least got you a little closer :-)

Comment: yes, variations of your answers made this.
Thanks for your support in cracking this.

Answer (score 2):

I am curious why you are storing an age as a String to start with, but that said, if you are able to use a Lambda, you can do a cast inside of a map step. Here is an example from my air-routes graph (runways is an integer type):

```
gremlin> g.V(3).values('runways').map {(String)it}.next().class
==>class java.lang.String
```

Cheers
Kelvin

Comment: Thanks kelvin.
It works in neo4j,
But didn't worked in AWS Neptune gdb. Could you help me with that.

Comment: When you tried it with Neptune what error message did you get? It's possible Lambdas like I used in my example are not supported yet.

Comment: I got the above exceptions with these queries.

Comment: Here are a couple of variations that you might try. The Neptune docs imply an additional next step may be needed.

   `g.V(3).map {(String)it.get().values('runways')}.next().class`

or you could try

     `g.V(3).map {(String)it.get().values('runways').next()}.next().class`

Comment: As you said, I tried the following query.    
**gremlin> `g.V(1).values('age').map{(String)it.get()}`** _=> 23_
 **gremlin> `g.V(1).values('age').map{(long)it.get()}`**
_Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=63e703c6-d100-46b8-bc6b-189fbb423b13, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=g.E('7ab1a023-d127-0214-9cbf-85554ef29cd1').values('count').map{(long)it.get()}, bindings={}, batchSize=64}}]._

_**I tried using long,Integer but didn't worked. My requirement is to cast String to Integer/long.**_

Comment: I tried adding next() step in the query with various combinations. The query worked with **casting from Integer to String**, but didn't worked with **casting from String to Integer**.

Comment: Rather than doing a cast you could try calling one of the helper methods like `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: here is an example of that:

`gremlin> g.V(1).map{Integer.parseInt(it.get().property('age').value())}.next().class
==>class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: yes I tried using **`Integer.parseInt(it.get()), it.get().toInteger(), Integer.valueOf(it.get()), (Integer)it.get()`** . and with use of next(), other variations, got this exception:`Cannot find matching method org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure`

Comment: Look closer at my example - after it.get() you need to get the specific property you care about.

Comment: sorry about that Kelvin, Even by using _**`it.get().property('age').value(), it.get().values('age')`**_ with helper methods like mentioned above(Integer.parseInt(), etc..). I've tried several swapping combinations with these keywords in this query, but giving the same exceptions.
Is there any alternate method for querying, other than map().

Comment: Have you considered just storing age as an integer in the graph to avoid needing this conversion?

Comment: There was pre-existing data with age as string in our GDB(3.2million Vertex). I'm not authorized to alter the data. So, I'm trying to cast the data within the query, which reduces the work of script. My need is to do math operations on it, which can be possible only on Integer family, and ease with gremlin. It would be helpful, If you had any suggestions for the query, which works on AWS-Neptune.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#w3aac12c22c10c15c47

> Neptune does not support Lambda Steps.

If I try the queries above I get:

> Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed...

Is this something that was supported in the past?

Comment: Yes, it was supported in preview version, but got deprecated with official release.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response. Is there an alternative then to do type casing in Neptune's queries?