# How do we convert string to number in a gremlin step?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a graph which has vertex E1 with property "price" and "name" which are storing String values. I need to calculate sum of the column "price" grouped by "name". I am writing the below query using Java:

```
g.withSideEffect("Neptune#repeatMode","BFS")
.V().hasLabel("E1").group()
.by("name").by(values("price").unfold().sum())
.unfold()
.project("rowName","data")
.by(select(keys).properties(MandatoryCustomerAttributes.firstName.name()).value())
```

I am getting this error:

```
{
"requestId": "38b781ce-fc02-4f7d-a71e-476dfd1925ce",
"code": "UnsupportedOperationException",
"detailedMessage": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"
```

}

Please help me in converting the String to any number format so that I can do some mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, you can not do such a conversion with Gremlin steps unless you use a lambda step (which is not always possible depending on the graph database you are using and since you tagged this question with Neptune, you definitely can't take that approach - [it also isn't advisable](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-lambdas)). You would need to store your data natively as a number or do the conversion and related mathematical calculation within your application. There is possibility that Gremlin will address this limitation in [3.7.0](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/future/#roadmap) as part of the various primitive operations aimed at `String`.

Comment: I had seen a solution in another thread but was not able to understand the solution. The thread is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266883/type-casting-in-gremlin-query

Comment: that solution uses a lambda. i'm not sure why the answer states that query works in Neptune, because Neptune does not support lambdas: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#w3aac18c16c10c15c79

Comment: I believe in its preview period (late 2017 - early 2018) Neptune allowed closures/lambdas. That capability was disabled in the GA release, June 2018. I’ll go back and edit that old answer.